# jQuery $.get then $.get

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

How do you daisy chain $.get calls like this:

```
let data1;
let data2;

$.get(data1URL).done((data) => {
  data1 = data;
  secondCall();
}).catch(error => console.log(error));

function secondCall() {
  $.get(data2URL).done((data) => {
    data2 = data;
    buildPage();
  }).catch(error => console.log(error));
}

function buildPage() {
  console.log(data1);
  console.log(data2);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jQuery.when` method.

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) )
  .then( myFunc, myFailure );
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: Thank you kindly sir!

Comment: Technically this is not chaining them.  They will both run asynchronously.

Comment: Yes, it not chaining. This function waits for all the passed functions to finish execution and executes return success or failure callback. For this question, it is a suitable option.

If you have a requirement, where the response of one AJAX call is input for next, then you can add the other AJAX call inside the complete/success callback of the first one.